# SpringDoc OpenAPI UI and wildcard path

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, wildcard, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am trying to use `springdoc-openapi-ui` in a Spring Boot project where `@GetMapping(path = "**")` **is necessary** (I have to use `**`, no way to avoid it). I went through many issues and discussion but I still can achieve only two situations:

- `swagger-ui.html` redirects correctly to `/swagger-ui/index.html` but that ends up in `**`.
- `/swagger-ui/index.html` works but other requests fail 404 (by registering webjars with `ResourceHandlerRegistry`)

The desirable state is when `/example` falls to `**` but `/swagger-ui.html`, `/swagger-ui/index.html`, and `/v3/api-docs/swagger-config` works as it should with `springdoc-openapi-ui`.

I created a simplified project for this issue: https://github.com/MarekSuchanek/spring-boot-openapi-test

Any hints/experience on this please?

Comment: All your configuration is being routed to "**" controller. You should change your DemoController configuration. With springdoc, there is no need to define WebConfig that implements WebMvcConfigurer. All, should be done using properties.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to have "**" there (the example is just a dummy example, in the real application that is more complex there is no way to avoid using **). Deleting WebConfig does not help...